# What does "taking copper at a ratio of 10 mg to 15 mg zinc for each milligram of copper" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> Most practitioners who supplement their patients' diets with zinc also recommend **taking copper** **at a ratio of 10 mg to 15 mg zinc for each milligram of copper**.

I think I understand
*"taking copper at a ratio of 10 mg to 15 mg zinc"*
which means if one takes 10 mg copper, one should also take 15 mg zinc.

The latter part *"for each milligram of copper"* throws me off. What does it mean? What is its connection to the preceding text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I misread it the first time too, before resolving it. It says

> Most practitioners / who supplement their patients' diets / with zinc / also recommend taking copper / at a ratio of / 10 mg to 15 mg zinc / for each milligram of copper.

So that means a zinc:copper ratio of between 10:1 and 15:1.

This ratio is confirmed here:

> [**Understanding Cronometer’s Nutrient Ratios – Zinc/Copper**](https://cronometer.com/blog/nutrient-ratios-zinccopper/)
>
> it is common practice to recommend a ratio of 8-15 mg of zinc for every 1 mg of copper

We would not say a ratio of 10:15 anyway, but 2:3.

Comment: Appreciate your answer, now I fully understand. The reason that I erroneously read it at first is because poping into my mind is the structure of using "ratio," ~ (of A to B) , from dictionary. In this case, however, the structure kind of shifts to "ratio of A for B, right?

Comment: Me too, at first I thought it was like the often-seen "1% to 2% of every ton."

Answer (score -2):

The instructions are very poorly worded.

They could want you to take 10-15mg copper for every one mg of zinc,
or want you to take 2 mg of copper for every 3 mg of zinc (10mg for every 15mg).

Both of these interpretations are equally valid. I hope you have enough context to make the correct decision.

Comment: @WeatherVane I̶'̶m̶ ̶g̶l̶a̶d̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶s̶o̶l̶v̶e̶d̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶b̶l̶e̶m̶.̶ ̶P̶l̶e̶a̶s̶e̶ ̶l̶e̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶r̶ ̶q̶u̶e̶s̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶u̶p̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶f̶u̶t̶u̶r̶e̶ ̶r̶e̶f̶e̶r̶e̶n̶c̶e̶,̶ ̶a̶s̶ ̶S̶t̶a̶c̶k̶E̶x̶c̶h̶a̶n̶g̶e̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶i̶n̶t̶e̶n̶d̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶c̶r̶e̶a̶t̶e̶ ̶a̶ ̶r̶e̶p̶o̶s̶i̶t̶o̶r̶y̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶a̶n̶ ̶a̶n̶s̶w̶e̶r̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶e̶v̶e̶r̶y̶ ̶q̶u̶e̶s̶t̶i̶o̶n̶.̶

Comment: Excuse me, it is not my problem or my question.

Comment: Wow, I should really go to bed. Sorry for my confusion.

Comment: You have the ratio reversed, sorry.